# how to over ride sinatra layouts the hard way?

Tags: sinatra

We have some rendering in our code that looks like this:

```
erb :login, :layout => :layout
<%= erb :_maintabs %>
```

I just wanted to change those lines of code to some one line functions like this
which would do the same thing:

```
erb :login, :layout => Main::get_layout
<%= erb Main::my_tabs %>
```

This would enable me to write some plugins to extend our code, but the guy I work with seems unexcited about that and doesn't want me to check those kinds of changes into the code. So my question is, is there a way I can modify sinatra rendering to render a different layout or view based on the layout name ? That over ride would have to be done at some lower level.

Comment: What is the expected output of doing `<%= erb Main::my_tabs %>` or passing `:layout => Main::get_layout` to `erb`? Are you trying to implement partials?

Comment: I want to be able to use my own plugins to add a debug gui to the site if I want better diagnostics. Otherwise all html has to be approved by the dev team and made pretty etc. I would like to be able to have hooks into our app so I can do that sort of thing

Comment: I just want to have Main::get_layout return :layout for the checked in code, that way I can easily override Main::get_layout in my plugin code to return the layout I want to use.

Comment: so as I said the guy I work with doesn't want me to have a method Main::get_layout in the checked in code, so I would like to figure out how to overide the erb() method in sinatra. If I know the method that gets called, I can easily save the old one, insert my method in the middle, do my thing and then call the old one, but offhand I am not sure what it would be. We use the sinatra register to register our modules that then have erb() calls in them

Comment: If I had time to grep through the sinatra code, maybe I could figure it out but I have been busy

Answer (score 0):

When I am in one of the routes that gets added by register(), it shows that I am in class Main and that Main has an erb() method so I guess I could try to overload that while saving the original and then call the original if I change the parameters in the middle or not.

```
app.get '/index' do   
  puts '---------------- in idx ---------------------- ' + self.class.to_s
  p self.methods
  erb :index, :layout => :layout, :locals => {:test_runs => test_runs, :tests => tests}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

## this seems to work and is what I was looking for,

## I overload the main class from my plugin

```
class Main


  def my_erb(view,opts={})
    new_view = view
    # puts '--------------------------- in ERB for template: ' + view.to_s

    if view.eql?(:layout)
      new_view = :my_layout
    elsif view.eql?(:_maintabs)
      new_view = :_my_maintabs
    end
    # puts 'view is now ' + view.to_s

    old_erb new_view,opts
  end

alias_method :old_erb, :erb
alias_method :erb, :my_erb



end
```